# Xampp не записывает log?

Tags: apache, xampp

**Используется**
Win-7;
xampp-7.1.7-0-VC14;

Xampp установил в папку: 
e:\srw\xampp_control\02\

**Проблема:** Apache не запускается.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что ошибки должны быть описаны в 
e:\srw\xampp_control\02\apache\logs\access.log;
e:\srw\xampp_control\02\apache\logs\error.log.
Но данные файлы пусты

**Вопрос.**
Почему Xampp не записывает log?

скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Из файла **httpd.conf**:

```
# The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
# If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
# container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
# define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
# logged therein and *not* in this file.
#
#CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
```

То есть в **logs/access.log** будет писаться лог только тогда, если нет других настроек в **\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**.

У меня в файле **httpd-vhosts.conf** есть такая секция:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "xxx/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Значит лог будет писаться в **logs/localhost-access.log**. У вас наверняка также или похоже.

Comment: Где находится файл `httpd-virtual.conf `? не могу найти у себя

Comment: e:\srw\xampp_control\02\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf Сорри, не virtual, а vhosts.

Comment: Что-то не пойму... сделал так `https://codeshare.io/al4yY8` не работает

Comment: Сложно сказать. Там других секций больше нет? Кстати, у меня порт 80, а не 8080. В httpd.conf какие значения у Listen и ServerName?